# How To Store A Element Inside A Map Using Dynamic Variable In Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I Wanted To Know How We Can Store Elements(Map) Inside A Map With Dynamic Element Names.
I Tried The Following

```
var activequestionid = "12201"
var aqid = "answers."+activequestionid
await updateDoc((doc(db, "tests", testid), {
      [`${aqid}`]: {ans:ans,type:type,time:serverTimestamp()}
    }))
```

```
var activequestionid = "12201"
var aqid = "answers."+activequestionid
await updateDoc((doc(db, "tests", testid), {
      [aqid]: {ans:ans,type:type,time:serverTimestamp()}
    }))
```

Also My Map Is As Follows:

```
testid(document)
    answers(map)
        12201(map)
```

But Both Give The Same Error: `Expected type 'Pc', but it was: a custom Object object`
Any Help On This Issue Is Appreciated!

Comment: `ans` = `a` and `type` = `tts_answered` when the above is being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `updateDoc()` function takes 2 parameters - a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference) and the data. You have `()` around both of them so essentially that's 1 parameter. Try removing them:

```
var activequestionid = "12201"
var aqid = "answers."+activequestionid

await updateDoc(
  doc(db, "tests", testid), {
    [aqid]: {
      ans: ans,
      type: type,
      time: serverTimestamp()
    }
  })
```